# Intuition behind log plotting

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, self-learning, matlab

The two plots are the same, except the 2nd one has been log transformed on the y axis.

Could I please draw your attention to what happens when Theta >0.65? After taking the log-lin plot it seems that the two lines are constant relative to each other. Is there nothing more interesting to say about this other than that it is due to the difference in y axis scaling?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The 3rd plot is plot(theta, [log(blue)-log(green)])**

**Additional Note**:  The green line is derived from the Blue line with this relationship:

Green = (0.95)*Blue^Theta

Comment: for starters; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-log_plot

Comment: Log scale on one of the axis allows to exhibit polynomial behaviour of the graph. The slope in this case represents the power which approximates it.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Could I please draw your attention to what happens when Theta >0.65? After taking the log-lin plot it seems that the two lines are constant relative to each other. Is there nothing more interesting to say about this other than that it due to the difference in y axis scaling?

Comment: @K.Rmth Ive had a read through that link, my specific question is in the above comment, I couldnt tag more than one person in it

Comment: If two functions are separated by a constant offset in a semi-log plot, that means $\log f(x) = \log g(x) + c$. Then the functions themselves are multiples of each other, $f(x) = e^c g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the difference between curves on a logarithmic scale looks constant, it means that one curve is scaled by some power of 10 (or whatever the logarithmic base is) from the other curve.

The difference in the curves can be seen as $\Delta_{\log} = \log y_1 - \log y_2$. Of course, using properties of logarithms, this is just
$$\Delta_{\log} = \log y_1 - \log y_2 = \log \frac{y_1}{y_2}.$$

Expanding this, you see that $$\frac{y_1}{y_2} = 10^{\Delta_{\log}},$$

or in other words,

$$y_1 = 10^{\Delta_{\log}}y_2.$$

---

The behavior on your lin-lin plot after $\theta > 0.65$ is because $y_2$, the slope of the green line, is large enough that the slope of the blue line gets exaggerated as well.

Comment: Arkamis il be honest and say Ive understood your answer, but can't seem to relate it to my context. could you help me out? Ive edited the question with the equation of the Blue Line in terms the Green line.

Comment: The answer is correct as it is, but the difference between the lines in the semilog plot is not really constant. The factor appears to be about 3 at the beginning, goes up to about 10, maybe 20, and then slightly down again. – @garciaj: it hasn't really become clear to me what that context is. If one line is derived from the other by a known formula, why are you trying to interpret plots? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @A.Donda, if you looked at my question edit i have given you how one line is derived from the other. Can you confirm that the difference between the lines in the semi log plot 'is not really constant'?  For my assignment I have to do a sensitivity analysis to parameters so all I need to do is say something interesting about how the two lines are affected by Theta. Im not really trying to get at anything in specific.

Comment: @garciaj, yes, your Additional Note is what I referred to. If you have that formula, what do you need the plots for? As for the difference, if you look closely you can see it is not constant. If you don't trust that impression, do a `plot(theta, log(blue) - log(green)` will show it more clearly, or `plot(theta, blue ./ green)` for the factor. – The problem is, you don't give enough of the context for us to tell what would be "interesting". Sensitivity of what to what? I'd recommend you edit your question to add that information. – I'm away now, but I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: I understand, its hard for me to give a context because Its not easy for me to summarise the problem! Do you have any thoughts on how "y1 = 10^deltalog * y2" in Arkamis' answer can be related to my  Green = (0.95)*Blue^Theta? Just help on linking these two  would allow me to interpret the context on my own

Comment: @A.Donda Sorry the previous comment was for you, i forgot to tag you. Ive also added a plot of theta and log(y1) - log(y2) and you were right its almost constant but a slight curve exists

Comment: @garciaj The constant offset you see in the log plot is constant in log space. Which means that it's a scalar multiple in linear space.

Comment: @garciaj, I gave it a try, see my answer. As I wrote before, the distance of the lines in the semilog-plot is not really constant. Btw., good that you added the third plot, but the log10 would have been more useful (my mistake). I also think you exchanged Blue and Green, because the log-difference should be positive, since Blue is larger than Green.

Comment: The fact that the offset is not constant isn't really much of a factor in the behavior of the plot at $\theta > 0.65$. It's close enough that the difference isn't the driving factor.

Answer (score 0):

You stated the relation between Blue and Green as
$$
G = 0.95 ~ B ^ \Theta
$$
`semilogy` shows data on the abszissa on a log$_{10}$-scale. Since 
$$
\log_{10}(G) = \log_{10}(0.95) + \log_{10}(B) ~ \Theta
$$
the difference is
$$
\log_{10}(B) - \log_{10}(G) = \log_{10}(B) ~ (1 - \Theta) - \log_{10}(0.95).
$$
This is clearly not constant, it depends on $\Theta$ directly and through Blue.

From your difference plot one can also see that the factor Blue / Green varies, from about 3 to about 20, or the log$_{10}$-distance from log$_{10}$(3) = 0.477 to log$_{10}$(20) = 1.301. Not a large change, but again, not constant.

The circumstance that the lines appear to be approximately parallel must have to do a) with the special form of the function Blue, and b) with the fact that our eye can't reliable judge the distance of sloped and curved lines.